# 3rd party transactions in PayPal

Tags: c#, paypal

I have a Partner Account and I have access to the 3rd Party, but I don't know how to get the transaction history.

Our issue is that we are unable to do API calls using the third party access token because we receive this message:

[image]

Comment: You need to add more details like what API are you using, what are your inputs. If possible, share the complete code for others to review and try.

Answer (score 0):

As the message says, you need to reach out to your PayPal Partner Manager to get permission for that call.

Stackoverflow can't help you with this.